# Prove $4-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[5]{5} \gt 0$

Tags: inequality, radicals

Is it possible to know if $4-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[5]{5} \gt 0$ without using decimal numbers?

Comment: The original title was correct; now it's wrong.

Comment: sorry, I do not understand. What is wrong? (the proof can result in "no")

Comment: In principle, either way, it should be possible to obtain close-enough rational approximations of the roots.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui You originally wrote $5-\sqrt2-\sqrt[3]3-\sqrt[5]5>0$ which was correct.

Comment: @George Law: it doesn't matter, the issue is find a method to say "yes, it is greater" or "no". First number (and, in fact, all remainders) are only examples.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Okay. But now you want to _disprove_ it rather than prove it.

Comment: The title is wrong because $4-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[5]{5}\lt 0$

Comment: For a harder one, you might try $7-20\,\sqrt {2}+2\,\sqrt [3]{3}-\sqrt [5]{5}-\sqrt [6]{6}+16\,\sqrt [7
]{7}
$.

Comment: Or $$12\cdot 2^{1/2}+9\cdot 3^{1/3}-21\cdot 5^{1/5} \stackrel{?}{<} 1.$$

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is not hard to verify following inequalities (just power both sides and it should result into simple inequalities in natural numbers only):

\begin{align}
\frac{4}{3} &< \sqrt{2} < \frac{5}{3}\\
\frac{4}{3} &< \sqrt[3]{3} < \frac{5}{3}\\
\frac{4}{3} &< \sqrt[5]{5} < \frac{5}{3}\\
\end{align}
Summing these up will give you
$$
4 < \sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[5]{5} < 5\\
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible infer a method for the general case from it? See by example comment of @Robert Israel

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Well generally for each summand you can find arbitrary close rational bounds, they just won't be so obvious as in this example.